# Dynamically increment name property in an html form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to send multiple data to the database at ince using a dynamically created form which add new fields when i cick in the ADD button. I have got most of the project to work, but to send the data to the controller i need to dynamiccally incerement the name property which i amn not able to do. I am new to spring ad Jquery. At the momemnt i can only send two array objects with index 0 and 1.

This is my html Form

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //group add limit
    var maxGroup = 10;
    
    //add more fields group
    $(".addMore").click(function(){
        if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup){
            var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
            $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
        }else{
            alert('Maximum '+maxGroup+' groups are allowed.');
        }
    });
    
    //remove fields group
    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
    });
});
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-secondary">
    
  <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/}" href="#">
  <img src="" class="logo" th:src="@{/image/logo.png}" alt="logo">
  Assam Power Distribution Company Limited</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   
  </div>
</nav>

<form method="post" th:action="@{/addfeeder}" th:object="${feeder}">
            
    <div class="form-group fieldGroup" >
        <div class="input-group mt-1 p-1 bg-light">
            <input type="text" name="feeder[0].feeder_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Feeder name" />
  <select name="feeder[0].feeder_type" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
    <option selected>Choose Capacity</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="33">33</option>
  </select>
          
            <input type="text" name="feeder[0].no_of_consumer_in_the_feeder" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Consumers"/>
            <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success addMore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT"/>
    
</form>


<!-- copy of input fields group -->
<div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
    <div class="input-group mt-1 p-1 bg-light">
        <input type="text" name="feeder[1].feeder_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Feeder name"/>
        <select name="feeder[1].feeder_type" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
    <option selected>Choose Capacity</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="33">33</option>
  </select>
        
        <input type="text" name="feeder[1].no_of_consumer_in_the_feeder" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Consumers"/>
        <div class="input-group-addon"> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller

```
    //adding feeder details
    @PostMapping("/addfeeder")
    public String addFeeder(@ModelAttribute FeederList feederlist)
    {

        System.out.println("Data"+feederlist);
        
        System.out.println(feederlist.getFeeder().size());
        
        for(Feeder c:feederlist.getFeeder())
               System.out.println(c);
        return "feeder";
        
        
    }
    
    public class FeederList {
        private List<Feeder> feeder=new ArrayList<>();

        public List<Feeder> getFeeder() {
            
             return feeder;
        }

        public void setFeeder(List<Feeder> feeder) {
             this.feeder = feeder;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Used `clone()` on page load to make a copy of the first group. When adding a new one we make another clone of the stored one
2. Creating a wrapping container for the groups making it simpler to append to
3. Created function `adjustNames()` that gets called when row added or removed. The remove process throws off indexing of names that follow it so seemed safest just to go through them all. You can see the text input names set as their values for verification in development

todo : Bug if remove all rows then add one. Perhaps prevent remove if only one left

```js
//group add limit
var maxGroup = 5;

var $groupContain = $('#group-container'); 

// clone first group
var $groupCopy = $groupContain.find('.fieldGroup').first().clone();
$groupCopy.find(':input').val('') // clear any values if prepopulated

//add more fields group
$(".addMore").click(function() {
  var groupLen = $groupContain.find('.fieldGroup').length
  if (groupLen < maxGroup) {
    var $newGroup = $groupCopy.clone();
    $groupContain.append($newGroup);
    adjustNames()
  } else {
    alert('Maximum ' + maxGroup + ' groups are allowed.');
  }
});

function adjustNames(){
  // clear console for demo 
  $groupContain.find('.fieldGroup').each(function(i){
     var $inputs =   $(this).find(':input[name]');
     // uses the group index to update array names
     $inputs.attr('name', function(j, currName) {    
      return currName.replace(/\[\d+\]/, `[${i}]`);      
    });
    // for demo set names in text fields
    $inputs.filter(':text').val(function(){
       return this.name;
    });    
  });
}

//remove fields group
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
  adjustNames()
});
```

```css
a{display:inline-block;padding:10px; font-size:1.2em}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form method="post" th:action="@{/addfeeder}" th:object="${feeder}">
  <div id="group-container">
    <div class="form-group fieldGroup">
      <div class="input-group mt-1 p-1 bg-light">
        <input type="text" name="feeder[0].feeder_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Feeder name" />
        <select name="feeder[0].feeder_type" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
          <option selected>Choose Capacity</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="33">33</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="feeder[0].no_of_consumer_in_the_feeder" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Consumers" />        
        <button class="remove"> Remove </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success addMore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!--<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT" />-->
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what i was  looking for . But for some reason the add button is not working ,when i click on the add button  nothing happens, the remove button seems to be working fine.

Comment: Are you copying it into the clone? I made sure add was outside of that row as it was originally being copied into it and having multiple "Add". If that's what you want you would need to delegate the event listener

Comment: no i mean, i may sound super dumb here, but the code seems to be working perfectly here when i run it(Run code snippet), but when i copy it on my page, the add button doesnt seem to do anything.

Comment: OK try adding back the `$(document).ready(function(){` . I removed it as it's not needed in stack snippets since the script is loaded after the html